# Clearing Simulink workspace saved with block diagram

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink diagram 'abc.slx' developed by a colleague. When I open the diagram, I get a warning:

```
Workspace for block diagram 'abc.slx' was not loaded because an error occurred while loading the MAT-file
   'C:\Users\roger\Dropbox\etc\abc.mat'
Cannot reload workspace from non-existing data source file:
   'C:\Users\roger\Dropbox\etc\abc.mat'
```

It's not surprising it can't load this .mat file: the path doesn't exist on my machine. I can't save the model, because I get a similar error.

What neither my colleague or I can figure out is how to remove the reference to this .mat file from the Simulink model. It doesn't need it, and as far as we can tell it only references data directly in the current workspace.

How can I find and delete the reference to this unnecessary .mat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Model Explorer (View -> Model Explorer or Ctrl-H) and select Model Workspace underneath you 'abc' model. Change the Data Source from 'MAT-file' to 'Model file'.

[image: Model Explorer]

Check this doc page for more information on the Model Workspace

```
web(fullfile(docroot, 'simulink/ug/using-model-workspaces.html'))
```